# How to recieve return value from python script to pre-commit hook

Tags: git, githooks

As apart of pre-commit hook i want to run a python script that returns a success value to a hook

some thing like that:

pre-commit hook

```
result=python test.py
if result exit 0
```

test.py

```
..running some tests...
return 1
```

is there any way to do that ?

thank you

Comment: You can write your Git hook in any language you like, provided your OS will let Git `exec` the hook directly. As to *how* to write a hook in some particular language, that's a question about programming in that language, not about Git.

Comment: Figure it out thanks

Answer (score 0):

By defining apython script file as a hook it possible to use a python script as a hook